# Why do these <li>s have extra height?

Tags: html, css

Here are two screenshots showing the issue I am facing:

[screenshot 1](http://cameronsflash.com/misc/sc1.png)
[screenshot 2](http://cameronsflash.com/misc/sc2.png)

You can see that the image has a height of 202px, but the li has a height of 208px

Where does the li get the extra 4 pixels of height from and how can I fix it?

Comment: Show the code, you probably have some margin or padding set to 3px for top and bottom

Comment: That's really hard to tell without the HTML/CSS source.

Comment: can be also a whitespace inside the li or something.

Comment: This could be caused by space after `<img />` tag. Try write `<li><img/></li>` - without spaces.

Comment: It's difficult for me to show the source since it's a drupal site running on my localhost. I can assure you that there is absolutely no whitespace in the li though (I had a similar issue that was caused by that). I have tried to make a cut down version of it in a static html file but for some reason the issue doesn't happen then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `display: block;` for images.

Answer (score 1):

I think you `li`s have `display: inline-block` set and that there are line breaks in your source code.

Try :

```
<li><img... /></li><li><img... /></li>
```

instead of

```
<li>
    <img... />
</li>
<li>
    <img... />
</li>
```

Or for readability

```
    <li><!-- HTML COMMENT : no line break
     --><img... /><!--
 --></li>
    <li><!--
     --><img... /><!--
 --></li>
```

Not so readable after all... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You must have some margin or padding remaining on your `<li>` set margin-top, margin-bottom and padding to 0 (or with negative size) on your elements. It can also due to the spaces in html tag (see comments on your post)

Give use a fiddle or the example, it's easier to help you with it.

Comment: As you see in Developer Tools - there is no margin / padding for top or bottom of li...

Comment: The browser can add it by default. Never used Chrome Developper Tools but I guess it doesn't show default values.